# Compare DSV with awk and delete differences by overwriting input file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm writing a bash script that, among other things, compares two pipe delimited value files $OLDFILE and $NEWFILE.

I've been successful in appending any records only in the $NEWFILE to the $OLDFILE with the following awk statement:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}!a[$4]' $OLDFILE $NEWFILE >> $OLDFILE
```

However, I also want to delete any records in $OLDFILE that aren't in $NEWFILE after first running the above. I hoped I could accomplish this with something like:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}a[$4]' $OLDFILE $NEWFILE > $OLDFILE
```

I thought that this would compare the $OLDFILE to the $NEWFILE and overwrite $OLDFILE with only the lines that matched, but awk is appending the output to $OLDFILE instead of overwriting it.

What am I missing?

I'm open to a better way of doing this, if anyone has a suggestion.

Comment: Can you do a cat on two files?

Comment: How do you mean? Like pipe the output from awk to cat and use cat to overwrite the original file?

Comment: No just cat $newfile and cat $oldfile for sample data.

Comment: There is information in another field in $OLDFILE that I need to preserve

Comment: Please edit your message to include some sample data, from both files. Also, do you know about the unix util `diff`? Sometimes it is easier to manipulate that output to achieve your goal. Or `sort` and `uniq` can help too. Good luck.

Comment: For this `comm` is probably going to be more helpful than `diff`

Comment: I do know about `diff`, but I didn't know that diff could delete text. Actually, I was using diff previously to tell me what was different so that I could manually delete the records.

Comment: `diff` doesn't delete text by itself, for that you really need to combine it with `patch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input. I was finally able to accomplish this with a mixture of my initial approach and using `comm`, as suggested by @Sorpigal. Here's my solution for posterity.

```
# This appends new entries from $NEWFILE to the end of $OLDFILE
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}!a[$4]' $OLDFILE $NEWFILE >> $OLDFILE

# This pulls out entries that are NOT in $NEWFILE but are in 
# $OLDFILE and should be deleted. It then outputs the entries to be 
# deleted to the $OUTFILE.
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}!a[$4]' $NEWFILE $OLDFILE > $OUTFILE

# This line will effectively delete any lines that are in both 
# $OUTFILE and $OLDFILE, thus finally deleting any records not in
# $NEWFILE.
comm -3 <(sort $OUTFILE) <(sort $OLDFILE) > combined.csv
```

Thanks again everyone who took a look at this, especially @Sorpigal!!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working and I'm sorry that I didn't get back to you with an answer right away,..

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are known to be in the same order in both files and both files are known to be sorted the same way, use `comm` (and if the files are **not** known to be sorted then some preprocessing with `sort` will fix it.)

```
comm -1 -3 oldfile newfile
```

This will list lines that appear only in newfile.

```
comm -1 -2 oldfile newfile
```

This will list lines that appear in both files only.

All together now

```
cat <(comm -1 -2 oldfile newfile) <(comm -1 -3 oldfile newfile) > combined
```

`combined` now contains lines appearing only in newfile plus lines appearing in both oldfile which were also in newfile.

Note: This is roughly the same as just saying `comm -1 oldfile newfile` but without any funny indentation.

Unfortunately you cannot write directly back into oldfile because it could be truncated before it is read. Just `mv -f combined oldfile` when you're done.

Comment: Does it matter if the file is sorted by a field other than the first?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is going to work. It's deleting some data from a column in $oldfile that I need to preserve. Unless there's a way to prevent that from happening, awk still looks like the most viable option.

Comment: @user981023: If some data is omitted this is because my guess as to which lines you wanted from where was wrong. If you can clarify then I can assist you in creating a form of this solution which will work. Questions: Are the columns always in the same order? Are the input files both sorted? Exactly which lines from oldfile do you need? Exactly which lines form newfile do you need? If you just want "Everything from oldfile and newfile, but no duplicates" then this is really easy.

Comment: Sorpigal the rows in the csv files do not match exactly. The $oldfile has a column "url" that has data for each record, but the corresponding column in $newfile is empty.

The comm commands you listed above are working as intended. It's copying the files only in $newfile to $oldfile and then checking the lines shared by both and `cat`-ing them together to make one list, which contains the correct records, however, the data in the "url" column in $oldfile is being overwritten by blank data for the "url" column from $newfile.

Much appreciation for the help. You're really going above and beyond.

Comment: @user981023: If you could update your question with a sample line from each file then I will update my answer with a resolution.